# Encryption size for DKIM Keys

Tags: dkim

I'm trying to determine what level of encryption salesforce supports for DKIM keys? In sum, when Salesforce generates a DKIM key, is it using 1024 bit encryption or 2048 bit encryption?

Answer (score 0):

It is using 1024 bits as of today, February 6th 2019. Keys are rotated often though.

Comment: Please include a link to the source for your answer. See [answer]

Answer (score 0):

The [salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=emailadmin_create_dkim_key.htm&type=5) does not explicitly describes the DKIM RSA key size, but the options are visible when creating a new key:
it is either 1024-bit or 2048-bit (attached screenshot for reference)

Take note of following recommendation, which is also mentioned in salesforce documentation in above link and setup page when creating a new key:

**Consider industry-specific security regulations or email recipient limitations when chosing a RSA key size. Some regulations, such as the Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS), require specific key sizes.**

[image]